# Nested array, return only user who is approved

Tags: javascript

I have output from backend like this.

```
 [
            {
                "id": 23,
                "who": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "user": {
                            "id": 9,
                            "username": "zorro",
                            "first_name": "Richard",
                            "last_name": "Zorro",
                            "avatar": "http://localhost:8000/media/default.png",
               
                        },

                        "approved": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "user": {
                            "id": 10,
                            "username": "mis2",
                            "first_name": "m",
                            "last_name": "s",
                            "avatar": "http://localhost:8000/media/default.png",
                        },
  
                        "approved": true
                    }
                ],
                "approved_looking": true,
                "who_add": 1
            }
        ],
```

im trying to return only user who is approved.
i have this code but it's return all users(two).. why?

```
        filteredUsers() {
            if (this.users) { 
                const filt = this.users.filter(x => x.who.filter((y) => {return y.approved === true}));
                return filt
}
        },
```

I wonder why it works like this

Comment: Well, let's say your object is `u = [ { "id": 23, ....} ]`.
Then your outer filter just says that `u[0]` passes the condition you give. But what you really want is something more like `u[0].who.filter((y) => {return y.approved === true});`. If you replace `this.users.filter` with `this.users.map`, you'll get something (but I'm not sure if that's exactly the result you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using two filters and the output is in the first filter level. Your inner filter is not working as you expect. It returns a JSON when finding an approved one and the first level filter considers it as `true` and you get the whole outer object, not the inner ones.

Try like this:

```js
const input = [ { id: 23, who: [ { id: 1, user: { id: 9, username: "zorro", first_name: "Richard", last_name: "Zorro", avatar: "http://localhost:8000/media/default.png", }, approved: false, }, { id: 2, user: { id: 10, username: "mis2", first_name: "m", last_name: "s", avatar: "http://localhost:8000/media/default.png", }, approved: true, }, ], approved_looking: true, who_add: 1, }, ];

const filteredUsers = (input) =>  {
  if (input) { 
      const filt = input.reduce((prev, curr) => {
        prev = prev.concat(curr.who.filter((y) => {return y.approved === true}))
        return prev
      }, [])
      return filt
  }
}

console.log(filteredUsers(input))
```

Using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)